# Plotting pandas groupy object as stacked horizontal bar chart

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I have a pandas `DataFrame` which I have used `groupby` on to put it into the following format:

```
Building Type 1            1000 - 3000m2      0.766355
                           3000 - 10000m2     0.140187
                           300 - 1000m2       0.084112
                           10000 - 30000m2    0.009346
Building Type 2            1000 - 3000m2      1.000000
Building Type 3            1000 - 3000m2      0.666667
                           3000 - 10000m2     0.222222
                           10000 - 30000m2    0.055556
                           300 - 1000m2       0.055556
Building Type 4            1000 - 3000m2      0.526316
                           3000 - 10000m2     0.473684
```

What I am trying to do with this is create a horizontal stacked bar chart with a bar for each building type. Essentially I would like to convert the data into the following format:

```
Building Type       300 - 1000m2    1000 - 3000m2   3000 - 10000m2  10000 - 30000m2
Building Type 1     0.084112        0.766355        0.140187        0.009346
Building Type 2                     1.000000
Building Type 3     0.055556        0.666667        0.222222        0.055556
Building Type 4                     0.526316        0.473684
```

What function do I need to use to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This was a lot easier than I thought. It's simply a case of calling `unstack` on the `groupby` object then plotting it.

```
df = grouped.unstack()
df.plot(kind='barh', stacked=True)
```

[Stacking and unstacking docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reshaping.html#reshaping-by-stacking-and-unstacking)

Answer (score 0):

```
piv = pd.pivot_table(datasetname, values="counts",index=["buildingtype"], columns=["m2"], fill_value=0)
```

Comment: Any reason that this is a better approach?

Comment: @kathleen, even though your answer might be correct, it would be nice if you commented it a bit.